# Problem installing Ubuntu 15.10 acer

Tags: uefi, 15.10, windows-8

I can not install Ubuntu appears to me as it is shown in the picture

[image]

**System Information**
[image]

OS: Windows8.1

**Please to help me quickly please.**

Comment: Maybe this post can help you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

What did you do to get that screen?  (List the steps).
How did you get that screen.

Try again.
Make sure you completely shutdown windows.  Turn off fast booting.
Hold the shift key continuously when you select the power menu and shutdown.

Make your ubuntu install disk with live linux installer.
Make 500 mb persistent.

Lastly, you could wait two weeks for 16.04 (!)